# linux scripting file check if this the last added user

Tags: linux, scripting

i want to say that he is not the last user that is created. 
Or that he is the last user that is created.

this is my script i've created:

```
#!/bin/bash
$laatst = $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd)
$laatste= $(tail -1 $laatst)

if [ $user = $laatste]
then echo "i am $user and i am created at last"
else echo "i am $user and i am not created as last"
echo "the last created user is $laatste"
fi
```

error:
./lastuser.sh: line 5: =root: command not found

does anyone know why this doesn't get the last added user name and some other errors?

Comment: `$lattste` is not executing `tail`. you forgot the $() or backticks.

Comment: `cut-d:` and `tail-1` are not valid commands. Assignments in `bash` are done like `x=something` with no spaces around the `=` and no `$` at the start of the variable name. `if[` is invalid. I'd suggest fixing at least these to start with. Indentation and other formatting to make it readable would be nice too. As it currently stands, you are not getting the error you claim you are, because it won't even execute as far as line 5...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no space before or after the '='.  Also when setting a variable there is no dollar sign in front of the variable.

Also the evaluation of the string is what you are looking for and that is what is applied to your tail command.

your if check needs spaces.

I don't see $user ever getting initialized to anything.

```
#!/bin/bash

laatst='cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd'
laatste=$($laatst | tail -1)
if [[ $user == $laatste ]]
then echo "i am $user and i am created at last"
else 
    echo "i am $user and i am not created as last"
    echo "the last created user is $laatste"
fi
```

~